# Similarity Proof, Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Geometry is not my strong suit and Im struggling with a problem I've been assigned.

I'm relatively familiar with proving the cosine rule, however I cant seem to complete part a of the question which is used in the steps of part b.

I started showing that angle AED and angle BEC are similar due to being vertically opposite, however, should i be also trying to determine side lengths to prove similarity between both these triangles as I am struggling to find any other aspects that show these triangles are similar.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks. (Question is attached)

**Question :**

[image]

Comment: There are 3 ways to prove two triangles are similar. One way is to prove there are two equal pairs of angles. In this case, AED is similar to BEC because the other pair of equal angles are $\angle DAE$ and $\angle CBE$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but why is ∠DAE equal to ∠CBE?

Comment: The reason that we use is called :"angles in the same segment". Another way to explain it is because (1) they both are located on the circumference of the circle: + (2) they both subtend the same arc (CD).